# How do get the value of input element of type "file"

Tags: javascript

I have tried to solve this problem without success. I want to get the "value" of an input element of "type = file". I don't know what I am doing wrong that's preventing me from getting the "input value".

```js
function addFile() {

  let toUpload = document.getElementById("fileid").click();
  console.log(toUpload.value);
  //Do something with file name;
}
```

```html
<button class=" btn border border-1
  rounded-pill " id="add-btn" onclick="addFile()">
    <i class="bx bx-plus-medical">
    </i>
    Choose file                  
</button>

<input id='fileid' type='file' hidden/>
```

The file upload dialogue comes up. But I cannot access the file name. Who can figure out an issue with the above code please?

Comment: I don't think you can hide an input like this, since the user needs to interact with it to add file.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — You can. It's a fairly common technique to provide a custom look and feel for a file input.

Comment: @Quentin I didn't see the click. I was struggling to see how the user would change the file

Comment: Aren't you trying to read `toUpload.value` before the user selects any file at all?

Answer (score 3):

You have **three** different problems here.

1. `click()` doesn't return the element, and the element has the value. Store the element in a variable and use that for reading and for clicking.
2. You need to wait until the user picks a file before reading the value, currently you are trying to get the value before it has changed. Use an event listener.
3. The value is an obfuscated path. Use the `files` property to get details of the files selected.

```js
function addFile() {
  let toUpload = document.getElementById("fileid");
  toUpload.addEventListener('change', event => {
      //Do something with file name;
      console.log(toUpload.value);  
      console.log(toUpload.files[0].name);
  }, { once: true });
  toUpload.click();
}
```

```html
<button class=" btn border border-1
  rounded-pill " id="add-btn" onclick="addFile()">
    <i class="bx bx-plus-medical">
    </i>
    Choose file                  
</button>

<input id='fileid' type='file' hidden/>
```

Answer (score 0):

input type file doesn't have a value, it will have a property called `files`

`files` is an array of files (in case the input allows multiple), each file will have a property called name to get the display name

Comment: It does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#value, but it won't help if a user picks multiple files